# r shiny folder input

Tags: r, shiny

I am hoping to include a widget in my R shiny app where the user can select a folder destination for output files to be saved in. I've tried using the `shinyDirChoose` and `shinyDirButton`, and they work, but moving through the file directory is **very** slow. I'd like to have the speed of `fileInput` and the ability to select a folder, rather than a file, as the file input (even though it would really be used for output). Is there a MIME type for folders in Windows Explorer that I could specify in `fileInput`? Or is there a way to speed up `shinyDirChoose`?

Comment: Are you trying to browse to a path on the client or the server? `shinyDirChoose` shows files on the server but `fileInput` shows files on the client. How slow is "very slow" exactly? Do you have a lot of files/folders present?

Comment: @MrFlick The app is used only within my organization where all employees can browse the same files, so it could be considered either client or server side. In `shinyDirChoose`  it can take about 15 seconds for the initial directory to show up. It takes at least 20 seconds after clicking a specific folder for its contents to show up. There are usually about 20 folders within each folder and a substantial amount of data in our files (upwards of 170 GB per file) which might have something to do with this. Is there a way to simply input folders with `fileInput`?